# Джанго условие 'IF' не работает с FilePathField

Tags: python, django

Я завис на проблеме с условием if в шаблоне с использованием поля  FilePathField

```
Models

class Comment(models.Model):
...
avatar = models.FilePathField(path='media/Avatar', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=('Аватар'))


Views
...
all_comments=Comment.objects.order_by('-id')[0:3]
```

Шаблон

Рабочий вариант:
Если поле ImageField то условие {% if k.avatar == NULL работает! %}, но поле не подходит, так как загружает файл, а мне нужно выбирать существующий.

Если в модели поле FilePathField (оно подходит) - любые из перечисленных условий {% if k.avatar == False %}, {% if k.avatar == NULL %} не работают.

Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы условия работали с FilePathField так же как с ImageField?

```
{% for k in all_comments %}
{% if k.avatar == False %}
<img src="/media/avatar/av1.jpg">
{% else %}
<img src="/{{k.avatar}}"">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Значение поля FilePathField — это строка. Строки никогда не бывают равны False, строки никогда не бывают равны None (а NULL в принципе не существует). Если вы хотите проверить отсутствие значения, почему бы не написать просто `{% if not k.avatar %}` и не мудрить?

Comment: Да, вспомнил python - работает! Спасибо огромное!!! Нужно отдыхать, а иначе элементарные вещи забываешь. Даже стыдно как-то за свой вопрос )))